# Android Wear to Android TV Communication

Tags: android, wear-os, android-tv

I'm looking for a way to have my android wear device locally communicate with my android tv. I was hoping that I could use the wearable Message API, which doesn't seem to work on android tv (probably because the android tv doesn't pair with android wear).

Ideally I was hoping if this would be possible without having to relay messages through the mobile phone app.

Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't connect to any other device directly, for example through Bluetooth or Wifi.

All connections need to go through Google Play Services using [Data Layer API](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/index.html) or [Channel API](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/ChannelApi.html?utm_campaign=playservices73-415&utm_source=dac&utm_medium=blog).

For that, all devices need to be paired using a Android Wear app. Theoretically you could install Android Wear app on the TV but I don't think it will be usable with the controller.